# hardware requirements for NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus, esb

We are in the process of planning a POC for NServiceBus.  I am trying to figure out what hardware requirements should be considered when deploying an ESB. Any general suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any more information about your application to help with more specific suggestions?

Comment: I'm from Particular Software, maker of NServiceBus. The requirements depend on your throughput, transport, etc, etc. If you contact our support, we can help out much better than via StackOverflow. But the minimum basically comes down to any server that can run .NET services.